# Need identical lines from file2 which are present in file1

Tags: awk, grep, comm

File1 contains numbers each per line (0 to 9 digit length) total records 20k
File2 contains numbers(0 to 9 digit) in first column  and other info in each line,total recs 46 ,000,00
Both files are sorted. Need to grep all recs from file2 which have common entries in file1

File1

```
988676562 

99373

133838000
```

File2

```
99373        dhdhdhdhd, 3838 dheueie,aaaa

133838000  rrtyusbjsjs,382 djdjdjsusu

2233747      Eheueueu. ,446,ttttiieenjs

44577333  Euedjdbebe,777,rrididjd
```

Output

```
99373         dhdhdhdhd, 3838 dheueie,aaaa

133838000  rrtyusbjsjs,382 djdjdjsusu
```

I tried `fgrep -f file1 file2` but the output is nil

Let me clarify first column are exactoy same in both the files

Comment: In my case `grep -f file1 file2` is working.

Comment: Are those dots at the end of the first column's data actually there?

Comment: @prvt_yadav add `77` to your keys file and watch it match `44577333`.

Comment: Yes first column in both the files are same. There is jo dot at the end of numbers.

Comment: I think, 2nd file is having 46 lacs records thats why grep is not working?

Comment: Related (possibly duplicate): [creating new columns](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/507719)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if your `File1` contains empty lines. That's why I make sure lines without numbers get ignored. Furthermore your sample `File1` seems to contain trailing spaces. That's way I will remove all leading and trailing non-digit characters.

You could use `sed` to create patterns for `grep` from this file and use the result as a pattern file to `grep` in `File2`.

```
grep -f <(grep '[0-9]' File1 | sed 's/[^0-9]*\([0-9]*\).*/^\1[^0-9]*.*$/' ) File2
```

This prints

```
99373         dhdhdhdhd, 3838 dheueie,aaaa
133838000  rrtyusbjsjs,382 djdjdjsusu
```

Explanation:

Extract lines that contain a number

```
grep '[0-9]' File1
```

Remove possible leading and trailing garbage and create a pattern for `grep` to find the nunber at the beginning of the line followed by a non-number character and anything else or by nothing up to the end of the line.

```
sed 's/[^0-9]*\([0-9]*\).*/^[^0-9]*\1[^0-9]*.*$/'
```

Answer (score 0):

For this kind of job, `join` is very useful. While using join keep in mind that both file are sorted on column, which are identical in both files.

Here is the solution

```
sort -o file1 file1 #sort and save content of file1
sort -o file2 file2 #sort and save content of file2
join file1 file2
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution (checking the empty lines):

```
while read line; do [ ${#line} -gt 0 ] && grep "$line" File2; done < File1
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below command tested and it worked fine

command

praveen@praveen:~$ `awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1];next}($1 in a){print $0}' file1 file2`

output

praveen@praveen:~$ `awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1];next}($1 in a){print $0}' file1 file2`

```
99373        dhdhdhdhd, 3838 dheueie,aaaa

133838000  rrtyusbjsjs,382 djdjdjsusu
```